# How can I install a signed release on pi3?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, iot

Headless Pi3, Android Things, running an irrigation app, connecting through wifi to provide a user interface through Nanohttpd. I should mention that the app is only for personal use on my pi - I am not trying to market it or run it anywhere else.

I have previously written about my irrigation app failing once a day or so without pertinent error messages. I have realised that it is because I have been using an unsigned apk for testing purposes, and I have now read that a time limited signature is added in the process. My app dies when it reaches the time limit.

So I have been trying to install a signed version and have failed so far.

I have uploaded a signed version to the Things console, and used this to generate a custom build. When I put the sd card in my pi, the app runs, but I don't get the chance to input the wifi connection details. I have tried to make my app not the default app, in the hopes of seeing the Things toolkit on boot, so I can input the wifi details. I haven't succeeded at that.

I have tried calling this code in my onCreate():

```
private void connectToWifi() {

        String networkSSID = "***";
        String networkPass = "***";

        WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
        conf.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";   // Please note the quotes. String should contain ssid in quotes
        conf.preSharedKey = "\""+ networkPass +"\"";
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
        //remember id
        int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
        wifiManager.disconnect();
        wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
        wifiManager.reconnect();
    }
```

and adding wifi/network permissions to AndroidManifest.xml but the app runs only briefly and I lose the wifi connection.

I have tried installing the signed version through Android Studio, but I get 'Password verification failed'. I have tried Cleaning and rebuilding the project.

I have tried using adb directly: 
adb install C:\AndroidStudioProjects\irrigator\app-release.apk
but I get

'Permission failure: com.google.android.things.permission.USE_PERIPHERAL_IO'

even though I have these permissions in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.things.permission.USE_PERIPHERAL_IO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and in the Things Console, I have ticked these permissions in the build process.

I don't know what to try next. Any help much appreciated.

UPDATE: I've tried downloading the signed version I have checked into Android console. Even though in the permissions list shown on the console it says:

```
android.permission.INTERNET
com.google.android.things.permission.USE_PERIPHERAL_IO
```

I still get the error showing in logcat:

```
 java.lang.SecurityException: Caller lacks required permission com.google.android.things.permission.USE_PERIPHERAL_IO
```

?

Answer (score 0):

adb install -r -g C:\1\app-release.apk

does the trick. I'd missed out the g flag. g grants all permissions.